# Reflect Table/Column names based on data annotation

Tags: c#, reflection, data-annotations

I want to derive table and column names at runtime based on data annotations. In my code sample I am hard coding values for now but I want to do it the right way. Searched around but I cannot find a solution.

```cs
[Table("T_MY_TBL")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("FNAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class MyLogic
{
    public void Save(List<MyTable> recs)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionsTring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                // want to reflect data-annotations instead of hard coding values
                using (var reader = FastMember.ObjectReader.Create(recs, "ID", "FNAME"))
                {
                    // want to reflect data-annotations instead of hard coding values
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "T_MY_TBL";
                    bc.WriteToServer(reader);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already doing it the right way. Your data model defines your application. If the types, columns and relations don't represent anything special and can just be fished out automatically, then why not just throw them into one table and let the application get on with it? There are tools which will turn your data model into an object model, but not by reading the schema at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of mapping libraries the can do this, but if you really need to do this with reflection, here you go:

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
  foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>() != null))
  {
    var tableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>();
    string tableName = tableAttribute.tableName; //whatever the field the of the tablename is

    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties().Where(property => property.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>() != null))
    {
      var columnAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();
      var columnName = columnAttribute.columnName; //whatever the field the of the columnname is
    }
  }
}
```